# Breeze assigns default value to Foreign Key property after setting it to null

Tags: breeze

We are still testing Breeze with Northwind database, and we encountered a strange behaviour.

First I am almost sure this is not a bug, it can't be, it is so basic operation.

We have a product entity and we set its SupplierID to null (foreign key is nullable) like this,

```
product.SupplierID(null)
```

after this breeze do these,

1. Set product's SupplierID value to null
2. Set product's Supplier to null
3. Set product's SupplierID to 0

and this causes a foreign key exception.

Probably this is a simple issue, we have to miss something, one of my collegue is trying to solve this since this morning, no luck.

He find out that after this assignment breeze call this twice (one for SupplierID and other for Supplier) and assign them nulls.

```
result = ko.computed({
                read: target,  //always return the original observables value
                write: function(newValue) {
                    instance._$interceptor(property, newValue, target);
                    return instance;
                }
            });
```

and after this breeze checks foreign key and executes this line,

```
if (property.relatedDataProperties) {
if (!entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
    var inverseKeyProps = property.entityType.keyProperties;
    inverseKeyProps.forEach(function(keyProp, i ) {
        var relatedValue = newValue ? newValue.getProperty(keyProp.name) : keyProp.defaultValue;
        that.setProperty(property.relatedDataProperties[i].name, relatedValue);
    });
}
```

it's interesting, this line checks if value is null (for product.SupplierID), and if it's null it sets to default value of Supplier table's key property, and it is 0 (it is not nullable because it is primary key).

We just updated to 0.80.2 version, but still same behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

Here is our test,

```
test("set foreign key property to null", 3, function () {
    var productQuery = new EntityQuery("Products").take(1)
        .expand("Supplier");

    stop();
    queryForOne(newEm, productQuery, "First Product")
        .then(assertProductSetSupplierIDToNull)
        .fail(handleFail)
        .fin(start);
});

function assertProductSetSupplierIDToNull(data) {
    var products = data.results;
    var firstProduct = products[0];

    ok(firstProduct.SupplierID(), "SupplierID is "+firstProduct.SupplierID());

    firstProduct.SupplierID(null);

    equal(firstProduct.SupplierID(), null, "is SupplierID null?");
}
```

and the result is,

[image]

Another interesting thing is, if we set this value twice like this,

```
    firstProduct.SupplierID(null);
    firstProduct.SupplierID(null);
```

test is passed,

[image]

I hope this sample would be enough to reproduce this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and is fixed in v 0.80.3 and available on the breeze website. ... and thanks for the unit test; it really helped.

Comment: Umut, please let us know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: It works great Jay, thank you very much. Also I want to thank you again for such a great tool :)